# Scaling the axes of an image plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have an image that I upload to my program. Then I plot it using plotly's image trace. What I need to be able to do is to set the range of these axes, without affecting the image being plotted.

[image: plot]

Above is what my plot looks like. If I simply divide the image array by a constant, I change the colors of my image. When I set a range, it makes the image black which is peculiar to me.

How would I have both the x and y axis go from [0:25.4]?

```
uploaded = files.upload()
filename = next(iter(uploaded))
figure = go.FigureWidget(data=[], layout=go.Layout())
figure.add_trace(go.Image(z=uploaded))
figure.show()

#more-or-less this should be a minimal reproducible example. 
#This is in google colab, hence the weird file upload method.
```

---

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the code.  Let me guess, this is a 1 inch square and you want it marked in millimeters?  ;)

Comment: Hahah, more or less yes. The graph is marked from 0 - 700 right now since it is in pixels. Realistically, I know the length and width of the image is 1in (25.4mm) for reasons. I will update my question with a working bit of the code.

Comment: The axes have a "scaleratio" that, I believe, define the ratio between pixels and axis units.  I suspect a value of 25.4/700 would do the job.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what happens here, I think you are right.

Comment: So the answer was actually a bit different. I had to set the dx and dy values to the 25.4/700 ratio, and now it works. Scaleratio seemed to distort the graph directly in some way, and I believe it is because the x and y axes are anchored by default. Oh well, got it working. Thank you for the help!